# Angular state not updating until click anywhere

Tags: javascript, angular

Very new to Angular, and just trying to get a feel for it. I have an input component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
})
export class InputComponent {
  q = '';

  queryChange(value: string) {
    this.q = value;
  }
}
```

It's html:

```
<div>
  <input #query type="text" (change)="queryChange(query.value)" />
  <button>Search</button>
  <div>{{ q }}</div>
</div>
```

When I type into the input, the `{{ q }}` doesn't update until I click anywhere on the screen, or hit enter. Almost like refocusing. Coming from React I'm confused as to why this happens with the Angular's `(change)` rather than updating as I type.

My first thought was that maybe because I'm passing the value of the input to `queryChange(query.value)` instead of passing the event value like I would usually do in React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is about the DOM and not Angular. You should use `(input)` instead of `(change)` if you want the event to trigger every time you type.

```html
<input #query type="text" (input)="queryChange(query.value)" />
```

See [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5vk17h?file=src/app/product-list/product-list.component.ts), as well as [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) and [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) MDN references. Specifically, MDN says about `change`:

> Unlike the `input` event, the `change` event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value.